# load php variable with jquery and work with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a php variable and want to use it for javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reload').load('http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/reload.php?uid=' + uid_clear + '');
});
```

From this code I get a `var` but I can only load this into a div

```
if (uid_clear == ..) {
    // want to replace the dots with the data from .load
    document.write(' Allgemeine Reloadsperre für das Mitglied von 30 Minuten');
}
```

How can I load the `data` into a `div` and use it as a javascript `var` ? Is there any way to transfer/change it or is it possible to load the data already as a javascript var ?

kind regards

Comment: Use ajax and you will get content into a var from success function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.get` like so:

```
$.get( 'http://www.domain.de/...', function( data ) {
  if (uid_clear == data) {
    // want to replace the dots with the data from .load
    document.write(' Allgemeine Reloadsperre für das Mitglied von 30 Minuten');
  }
});
```

Check out [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more info about the `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make a hidden input, put your PHP variable in this hidden input, instead of into div.
Then get this html value in js with js/jquery.

#### HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_value_from_php" value="<?php echo $your_PHP_var; ?>"/>
```

#### JQUERY

```
var uid_clear = $('#my_value_from_php').val();
// you can use your js variable now
```